# Database Design for Historical Aggregation

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-warehouse

I am trying to decide which would be the best data warehouse type design.  It will be used to find historical price averages of different item during different time periods using a Google type search.  For example, what was the avg price of Stock A this month, 3m, 6m, and 1 year ago?  The issue is that I do not have an item name that I can use, I have descriptions fields about the item.

This means that I can't aggregate items into views, since the same item maybe listed 20 times each with different descriptions, so I have to on the fly do a full-text search on the description field, grab the price where the insertdate is < 3 months ago.  Then find the average of that.

So is my best bet to have everything in one table like:

```
            MAIN
----------------------------
ID | Description | Price | Date
```

---

**or many tables:**

```
    DESCRIPTION
------------------
ID | Description | 


   PRICE
---------
ID | PRICE
```

And just join to get the data I want.  The database will contain a few million rows.  If I had a way to get the real name of the item I could see pre aggregating the data, but that is not an option for me.  I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say option 2 ... keep the top level details in the "description" table. And the historic data in the "price" table (albeit, with a Date field added to capture the temporal value)

Comment: this may be my best bet since i am using mysql, it would allow me to run myisam for full text search on just the description table, all else can be innodb.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel suggested, Option 2 is likely going to provide you more flexibility. I would suggest including additional dates in each table to accomodate for slowly changing dimensions. Descriptions and other attributes about a given item may change over time.

In the case of a brick and mortar retailer, you would quite likely include the Store ID as well because items are quite likely priced differently in different locations due to competition and demographic make-up of your customers near a given location.

```
    DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------------------------
ID | Description | Effective Date | Expiration Date


   PRICE
-----------------------------------------------------------
ID | Location ID | Price | Effective Date | Expiration Date
```